# Macのターミナルで「node -v」を実行すると、「-bash: /usr/local/bin/node: No such file or directory」と表示される

Tags: node.js, bash

表題の通り、Macのターミナルで `node -v` を実行すると、"-bash: /usr/local/bin/node: No such file or directory" と表示されております。

**やったこと**

1. homebrewでnodeをアンインストール（アンインストール前は「node -v」コマンドでnode.jsのバージョンが表示されておりました。）
2. `nodebrew install-binary latest` で安定版のnode.jsをインストールしました。
   `nodebrew -list` の実行結果は次の通りです。

```
$ nodebrew list
v10.0.0
v11.14.0
v12.16.3
v16.2.0

current: v12.16.3
```

3. `node -v` を実行すると、下記結果となります。

```
$ node -v
bash: /usr/local/bin/node: No such file or directory
```

.bash_profileの中身は下記の通りですので、パスの設定はされているとの認識です。
（ここはnodeのアンインストール前から設定されていたのでいじっていません）

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  . ~/.bashrc
fi
export PATH=$HOME/.nodebrew/current/bin:$PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@8.0/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="~/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi
```

以下のページやその他色々参考にやってみたのですが、うまくいかず止まってしまっているため、こちらで質問させていただきました。

[nodebrewでnodeのバージョンを切り替える方法](https://qiita.com/kuriya/items/36ae29366df0b7c95dec)

解決方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えていただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

こちらを読んでいて、ターミナルを再起動したら問題なく表示されました。

[MacにNode.jsをインストール](https://qiita.com/kyosuke5_20/items/c5f68fc9d89b84c0df09)

そのため、解決済みとさせていただければと思います。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: 参考までに、ターミナル(シェル)を再起動する以外にも `hash -r` を実行すると同じ効果が得られます。これは bash の内部に保持されている、コマンド名とそのファイルパスを記録しているハッシュテーブルをクリアします。

Comment: ご教示いただきありがとうございます。
bashの内部でハッシュテーブルに保存しているのですね。
その辺りまで手が回っておらず、今後知識を深めていければと思います。
よろしくお願いいたします。